# Webkit-tap-highlight-color won't change on focus

Tags: css, tailwind-css, skeleton-ui

I'm building a form using Svelte & Skeleton UI.

The `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` gets set to `rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);` by the theme.

This gives an unwanted effect on some buttons causing the border color to change when an items is pressed or in focus (e.g tabbing to the element).

Current behaviour / Expected border behaviour

[image] [image]

I have tried setting the `focus:` and `focus-visible:` psuedo classes to `border-color-*` and tried manually overriding the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` using the `!important` property but nothing wants to override the default behaviour.

The code

```
<footer class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn border rounded-md border-red-600 bg-red-300/10 hover:bg-red-500/30 focus:border-red-500 focus-visible:border-red-500" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent !important;" on:click={modalStore.close}>Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn border rounded-md border-success-600 bg-success-300/10 hover:bg-success-500/30" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent" on:click={onFormSubmit}>Send message</button>
</footer>
```

What other CSS classes can interfere with this and what should I look out for?

Edit:
Setting `focus:ring-0` also does not get rid of the white border.

Edit 2: It stays this way across multiple browsers (chrome, firefox, edge) & the css `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` (with the important property) does get applied (I see it in the inspector as element.style) but it doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white (and black, though you cannot necessary see the black portion in your screenshots) is the focus outline applied by browsers. You can override this using the [`outline-*` CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).

With Tailwind, it has separate sets of utility classes to set [`outline-width`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/outline-width), [`outline-color`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/outline-color), [`outline-style`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/outline-style) and [`outline-offset`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/outline-offset).

For example, to change the outline to blue, we can use the `focus:outline-blue-500` class:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<footer class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn border rounded-md border-red-600 bg-red-300/10 hover:bg-red-500/30 focus:border-red-500 focus-visible:border-red-500 focus:outline-blue-500" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent !important;" on:click={modalStore.close}>Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn border rounded-md border-success-600 bg-success-300/10 hover:bg-success-500/30 focus:outline-blue-500" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent" on:click={onFormSubmit}>Send message</button>
</footer>
```

Comment: Changed my button to
`<button class="btn border rounded-md border-red-600 bg-red-300/10 hover:bg-red-500/30 focus:outline-red-500 focus-visible:outline-red-500" on:click={modalStore.close}>Cancel</button>` but the issue persists (seems like it doesn't actually get applied in my CSS either. May be an issue with my tailwind rather than the CSS selectors